# Recreating store takes a lot of time

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Kafka streams using spring cloud streams. I do an aggregation when data is being consumed from a topic. The data end up in the several stores I have defined. When stopping the app and restarting,  it takes quite a while before the application becomes ready due to the recreation of the store. Any idea if this is common? I would expect this to be rather quick as the store gets persisted outside of the app.

Regards

Michael

**Update 4th of Februari**
To be more clear, the store gets persisted outside of the app, outside of the container. So that should be everything there is to it right?

Comment: I am not sure how you deploy your application, however, if you restart instances *in the same machines* they should startup quickly. Only if you restart them on new nodes, states needs to be re-created that can take some time. Thus, is recommended to not move your instanced to different machines. If you run on Kubernetes, you might want to attach state to your PODs.

Answer (score 1):

By default, state store data is backed by Kafka topics. If a Kafka Streams instance starts, it looks for its state store data (in directory defined by `state.dir`). If it doesn't find it, it will have to read it from state store topics in Kafka. Depending on the amount of data you have, this may take some time.

An example of this happens when running on containers. If you are not using volumes to persist data beyond the life of your container, the Kafka Streams application instance will have to recreate it every time reading from the topics; so you can shorten this time by detaching this storage from the life of your container so it's available on restart.

*Updated Answer*: Yes, although bear in mind that you would lose it if the  volume is a plain volume in the host, because in that case it will not be lost with your container, but it would be lost if your host machine die. For extra fault tolerance you may want to have it persisted not only detached of your container but of your host machine as well (e.g. in AWS terms, external volumes(WBS) vs instance volumes).

Also, it would help to set `num.standby.replicas` higher than 1, so another instance may take over on stopping of an instance. Bear in mind that this will of course put some extra strain in your instances.